# compare current date with existing dates in Dynamodb table in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Contact center should not work on holidays so for that we are trying to add holiday list in dynamodb table(which has only one column "date") and write a lambda which will compare with the current date

1. If the date matches it has to return true
2. If the date does not match it has to return false

Using this link [https://www.fernandomc.com/posts/eight-examples-of-fetching-data-from-dynamodb-with-node/][1] reference i tried match the current date with existing values
but somehow it is returning **Error:**"**UnexpectedParameter**: Unexpected key '7' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':date']"

**Edited**

Table : Partition key: date (String) and the format is YYYY-DD-MM

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

exports.handler = async (event) => {
   let response = '';
   var tableName = "table";

   const currentdate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

    try {
         var params = {
        KeyConditionExpression: '#D = :d',
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
           ':d': { S: currentdate }
           },
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
           '#D': 'date'
           },
          TableName: tableName
      };
       var result = await dynamodb.query(params).promise()
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
       return true;
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
       return false;
  }
   };
```

Comment: What typeof date type are you using in DynamoDB? Just curious if you are using AWSDateTime and if hat format is related to your error. I know Python doesn't support this type even though it's part of the ISO 8601 standard. This may not be an issue with Javascript though. Can you try using two text strings which represent your date and see if you get the same error?

Comment: I am using data type as string with YYYY-DD-MM format

Comment: Please share the entire code snippet, and the variables that are in use. Also, is `date` the partition key for the table?

Comment: edited the post with code and table details

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems.

Your `ExpressionAttributeValues` has the incorrect syntax - you need to tell DynamoDB what data type the field is, like this:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ':d': { S: currentdate }
},
```

`date` is a reserved word in DynamoDB, so you will need to add an `ExpressionAttributeNames` clause too, like this:

```
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
  '#D': 'date'
}
```

Which also necessitates you changing the `KeyConditionExpression` to:

```
KeyConditionExpression: '#D = :d'
```

[Double check the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property) if need be.

And just in case you do actually store the date in `YYYY-DD-MM` format, an ISO date is `YYYY-MM-DD`. I'm just assuming this is a typo, however.

Comment: Thanks for the input, tried those but still i am facing same issue "event_listeners.js:132:42)
        at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20) {
      code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
      time: 2023-01-10T09:35:44.144Z
    },
"

Comment: My bad, I've updated my answer. My answer should have said `ExpressionAttributeNames` for the second code block, not `ExpressionAttributeValues` (Names vs Values at the end). Let me know how that goes.

Comment: no problem, i added that, thanks for that i am able to get the result  but how am i matching current date with db values am unable to understand and it is returning false on error not on matching right Even i give wrong value it is returning true which should return false

Comment: It will only give you an error if there's an actual error in execution, such as a network error or bad input. An empty result is not an error, so it will return true, even with an empty result set. You will need to check the result returned to see if it actually returned any matches or not. The `Count` key in the response should tell you if there were any results or not.

Comment: Thanks i did it, did check the count and returned true when matched and false when it does not but what to give as value(when namespace will be external) in check contact attributes in contact flow and ofcourse condition will be true or false